# Problem implementing Interceptor pattern

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, implementation

I'm attempting to develop an Interceptor framework (in C#) where I can simply implement some interfaces, and through the use of some static initialization, register all my Interceptors with a common Dispatcher to be invoked at a later time.

The problem lies in the fact that my Interceptor implementations are never actually referenced by my application so the static constructors never get called, and as a result, the Interceptors are never registered.

If possible, I would like to keep all references to my Interceptor libraries out of my application, as this is my way of (hopefully) enforcing loose coupling across different modules.

Hopefully this makes some sense.  Let me know if there's anything I can clarify...

Does anyone have any ideas, or perhaps a better way to go about implementing my Interceptor pattern?

**Update:** I came across Spring.NET.  I've heard of it before, but never really looked into it.  It sounds like it has a lot of great features that would be very useful for what I'm trying to do.  Does anyone have any experience with Spring.NET?

TIA,
Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend looking at some of the existing Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) frameworks for .NET since they will likely accomplish what you're trying to achieve in a more generalized and maintainable fashion. Most of them are open source, so where they don't meet your needs you may be able to extend and contribute to the project(s).

More details: http://www.sharpcrafters.com/aop.net

Comment: +1 I'd recommend Spring & NHibernate for a sample of this pattern. You can also check to see how Http Modules are handled in the asp.net framework. It'll probably be more involved than the other two, but it is another way of building interceptor framework.

Answer (score 0):

Spring.NET, Unity Framework and StructureMap are probably your best bet.  What I have done in the past is used MVC and created a custom controller factory to generate my controllers.  However using dependency injection became difficult with frameworks like NinJect because of it's lack of an XML configuration (Ninject uses a fluent API).  The reason it's difficult ofcourse is that you are not sure at runtime what modules you will need dependency injection for.

The three IOC containers above all have some form of XML configuration which can be modified outside of your compilation and therefore help to make your application more modular, so there would be (hopefully) no need for static initialization.  The major plus being that you don't have to worry as much about thread safety.